# Merge hashes based on particular key/value pair in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am trying to merge an array of hashes based on a particular key/value pair.

```
array = [ {:id => '1', :value => '2'}, {:id => '1', :value => '5'} ]
```

I would want the output to be

```
{:id => '1', :value => '7'}
```

As patru stated, in sql terms this would be equivalent to:

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM Hashes GROUP BY id
```

In other words, I have an array of hashes that contains records. I would like to obtain the sum of a particular field, but the sum would grouped by key/value pairs. In other words, if my selection criteria is :id as in the example above, then it would seperate the hashes into groups where the id was the same and the sum the other keys.

I apologize for any confusion due to the typo earlier.

Comment: you might need to be consistent with your keys are they strings or symbols

Comment: Do all the hashes in the array have an `:id` and `:value` key, and is the id always 1?

Comment: I would guess you like to *sum* the `:value` attributes for the hashes having a particular `:id` as you would in an SQL statement `SELECT SUM(value) FROM Hashes GROUP BY id` if you get what I mean. Could you clarify please?

Comment: key in one hash is symbol and in another it is string. Please update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: The question has been clarified since I first posted my answer.  As a result, I have revised my answer substantially.

Here are two "standard" ways of addressing this problem.  Both use [Enumerable#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) to first extract the elements from the array (hashes) that contain the given key/value pair.

**#1**

The first method uses [Hash#merge!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) to sequentially merge each array element (hashes) into a hash that is initially empty.

**Code**

```
def doit(arr, target_key, target_value)
  qualified = arr.select {|h|h.key?(target_key) && h[target_key]==target_value}
  return nil if qualified.empty?  
  qualified.each_with_object({}) {|h,g|
    g.merge!(h) {|k,gv,hv| k == target_key ? gv : (gv.to_i + hv.to_i).to_s}}
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [{:id  => '1', :value => '2'}, {:id => '2', :value => '3'},
       {:id  => '1', :chips => '4'}, {:zd => '1', :value => '8'},
       {:cat => '2', :value => '3'}, {:id => '1', :value => '5'}]

doit(arr, :id, '1')
  #=> {:id=>"1", :value=>"7", :chips=>"4"}
```

**Explanation**

The key here is to use the version of `Hash#merge!` that uses a block to determine the value for each  key/value pair whose key appears in both of the hashes being merged.  The two values for that key are represented above by the block variables `hv` and `gv`.  We simply want to add them together.  Note that `g` is the (initially empty) hash object created by `each_with_object`, and returned by `doit`.

```
target_key = :id
target_value = '1'

qualified = arr.select {|h|h.key?(target_key) && h[target_key]==target_value}
  #=> [{:id=>"1", :value=>"2"},{:id=>"1", :chips=>"4"},{:id=>"1", :value=>"5"}] 
qualified.empty?
  #=> false 
qualified.each_with_object({}) {|h,g|
  g.merge!(h) {|k,gv,hv| k == target_key ? gv : (gv.to_i + hv.to_i).to_s}}
  #=> {:id=>"1", :value=>"7", :chips=>"4"}
```

**#2**

The other common way to do this kind of calculation is to use [Enumerable#flat_map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), followed by [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

**Code**

```
def doit(arr, target_key, target_value)
  qualified = arr.select {|h|h.key?(target_key) && h[target_key]==target_value}
  return nil if qualified.empty?  
  qualified.flat_map(&:to_a)
           .group_by(&:first)
           .values.map { |a| a.first.first == target_key ? a.first :
             [a.first.first, a.reduce(0) {|tot,s| tot + s.last}]}.to_h
end
```

**Explanation**

This may look complex, but it's not so bad if you break it down into steps.  Here's what's happening. (The calculation of `qualified` is the same as in #1.)

```
target_key = :id
target_value = '1'

c = qualified.flat_map(&:to_a)
  #=> [[:id,"1"],[:value,"2"],[:id,"1"],[:chips,"4"],[:id,"1"],[:value,"5"]] 
d = c.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {:id=>[[:id, "1"], [:id, "1"], [:id, "1"]],
  #    :value=>[[:value, "2"], [:value, "5"]],
  #    :chips=>[[:chips, "4"]]} 
e = d.values
  #=> [[[:id, "1"], [:id, "1"], [:id, "1"]],
  #    [[:value, "2"], [:value, "5"]],
  #    [[:chips, "4"]]] 
f = e.map { |a| a.first.first == target_key ? a.first :
  [a.first.first, a.reduce(0) {|tot,s| tot + s.last}] }
  #=> [[:id, "1"], [:value, "7"], [:chips, "4"]]
f.to_h => {:id=>"1", :value=>"7", :chips=>"4"}
  #=> {:id=>"1", :value=>"7", :chips=>"4"}
```

**Comment**

You may wish to consider makin the values in the hashes integers and exclude the `target_key/target_value` pairs from `qualified`:

```
arr = [{:id  => 1, :value => 2}, {:id => 2, :value => 3},
       {:id  => 1, :chips => 4}, {:zd => 1, :value => 8},
       {:cat => 2, :value => 3}, {:id => 1, :value => 5}]

target_key = :id
target_value = 1

qualified = arr.select { |h| h.key?(target_key) && h[target_key]==target_value}
               .each { |h| h.delete(target_key) }
  #=> [{:value=>2}, {:chips=>4}, {:value=>5}] 
return nil if qualified.empty?
```

Then either

```
qualified.each_with_object({}) {|h,g| g.merge!(h) { |k,gv,hv| gv + hv } }
  #=> {:value=>7, :chips=>4}
```

or

```
qualified.flat_map(&:to_a)
         .group_by(&:first)
         .values
         .map { |a| [a.first.first, a.reduce(0) {|tot,s| tot + s.last}] }.to_h
  #=> {:value=>7, :chips=>4}
```